# Mid Function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to translate an access query into SQL Server 2008, but it doesn't seem to like my MID statement (or my InSTR for that matter).  How would I equate this to a SQL Server Query?

```
Mid$([a]![POName],(InStr([a]![POName],"-")-1)))
```

Comment: `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` are the equivalent for the Mid and InStr functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you want:

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(10) = 'AA-BB'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@S, CHARINDEX(@S, '-') - 2, LEN(@S))

>> AA
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the $, swap, ! with . and change double quotes to single -

```
Mid(a.POName,(InStr(a.POName,'-')-1)))
```

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, I'm not sure INSTR will work, you'll need charindex

Comment: `Mid` and `InStr` functions are only available SQL 2012+ I think. But the OP asked for SQL 2008.