# MS Access mid equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have the following SQL statement; the problem is that the `MID` function is not recognized. Is there an equivalent to `MID` in SQL Server? Thanks

SQL:

```
SELECT 
    tblHR_Employees.ADLoginID AS bar,
    Replace(LCase(Mid([LikesToBeCalled], 1, 1) & [lastname]), ' ', '') AS foo
FROM 
    [STONE_DB].[dbo].[tblHR_Employees]
WHERE 
    tblHR_Employees.ADLoginID IS NULL
    AND tblHR_Employees.SeparationDate IS NULL;
```

Returns:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
>   'Mid' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: [**`substring()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) would be the equivalent -- and [**`lower()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lower-transact-sql) would be the equivalent of `LCase()`

Comment: OH man yes it is. Please answer so i can mark it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mid Function in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846579/mid-function-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`substring()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) would be the equivalent -- and [**`lower()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lower-transact-sql) would be the equivalent of `LCase()`

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 
    tblHR_Employees.ADLoginID AS bar,
    Replace(LOWER(SUBSTRING([LikesToBeCalled], 1, 1) & [lastname]), ' ', '') AS foo
FROM 
    [STONE_DB].[dbo].[tblHR_Employees]
WHERE 
    tblHR_Employees.ADLoginID IS NULL
    AND tblHR_Employees.SeparationDate IS NULL;

Comment: If I may recommend putting code in the `code block` and add some context to your code